# Find Fourier half range sine Series for $f(x)=x(\pi-x)$ on $(0,\pi)$.

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I tried finding the Fourier coefficient  $ b_n$  but it came zero.

**My attempt:**

$ b_n=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi-x)\sin(2nx)dx\\
=\frac{4}{\pi}\left\{\pi\int_0^\pi x\sin(2nx)dx-\int_0^\pi x^2\sin(2nx)dx\right\}\\
=0$

**Correct answer is:**

$\frac{8}{\pi}\left(\frac{\sin x}{1^3}+\frac{\sin3x}{3^3}+\frac{\sin5x}{5^3}+...\right)$

Comment: Can you please show how you evaluated the integrals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should integrate
$$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi } x (\pi -x) \sin (n x) \, dx=\frac{4-2 \pi  n \sin (\pi  n)-4 \cos (\pi  n)}{\pi  n^3}$$
to get coefficients
$$\frac{8}{\pi },0,\frac{8}{27 \pi },0,\frac{8}{125 \pi },\ldots$$
and finally
$$\frac{8}{\pi}\left(\sin x +\frac{\sin 3x}{3^3}+\frac{\sin 5x}{5^3}\ldots\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

The correct formula for $b_n$ is $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x(\pi-x)\sin(nx)\,dx$$